# Creating Test Spec for @Input function angular 2

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

```
    @Input()
    public set isRunning(value: boolean) {
        if (!value) {
            this.cancelTimeout();
            this.isDelayedRunning = false;
            return;
        }

        if (this.currentTimeout) {
            return;
        }

        this.currentTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.isDelayedRunning = value;
            this.cancelTimeout();
        }, this.delay);
    }
```

The code above is an @Input for an angular 2 component. I have a problem in creating a test case for the input as I do not know how to create a test for this  kind of input. Should I create a getter? How do I do this? I cannot find any reference for this.

Answer (score 1):

With a setter (`set`), all you do is assign the value to the property (method)

```
let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
let component = fixture.componentInstance;l
component.isRunning = true;
fixture.detectChanges();
```

For the timeout, you might need to do something like

```
import { fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing;

it('should change isDelayedRunning', fakeAsync(() => {
  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
  let component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();

  component.isRunning = true;
  // wait for timeout
  tick(200);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(fixture.componentInstance.isDelayedRunning).toBe(true);
}));
```

`fakeAsync` won't work if you are using `templateUrl` in your component. So you have to use `async`. But AFAIK, there's no facility like `tick` where we can control the wait period, so you might have to just set a timeout in the test

```
import { async } from '@angular/core/testing';

it('should change isDelayedRunning', async(() => {
  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
  let component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();

  component.isRunning = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.isDelayedRunning).toBe(true);
  }, 200);
}));
```